# Eclipse: Connecting a TextEditor to the Properties View

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am currently implementing an Eclipse-Plugin which is using the standard properties view, connected to a Navigator. It also features a textual editor, which is able to connect regions within its' document to certain objects that can supply properties to the PropertiesView (i.e. the same objects, that are displayed in the Navigator).
However, the Tuturials I found only dealt with Views that used a pre-implemented Viewer, which already supported passing on the selected element to the Properties View.
The TextEditor does not do that (I am using jface and a subclass of the AbstractTextEditor class), because it's SelectionProvider returns informations about the offset and the length of the selection only.
How do I have to modify the SelectionProvider of my TextEditor, such that it provides information usable to the Properties View?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have managed to find the solution myself.

First of all, I had to implement the `getAdapter()` method in my subclass of `TextEditor` such that it returns an Adapter for `IPropertySourceProvider`, that can deal with the type of elements that are selected in my `AbstractTextEditor`.

Then, I implemented an `ISelection` that extended `TextSelection`, in order to not interfere with any selection-specific mechanism supplied by the AbstractTextEditor, and implements the interface `IStructuredSelection`, because the Properties View works with this interface of `ISelection` only.

An `IStructuredSelection` features basic methods of an array, however, in my case it is only possible to ever select only a single element, so implementation of these methods were trivial.

The last step was to get my `ISelection` to the right place. Overwriting the `getSelection()`-method of the `ISelectionProvider` of the AbstractTextEditor did not suffice, because obviously, the methods of firing `SelectionChangedEvents` does not use this method.

Thus, instead of using a standard `SourceViewer`, I used my own implementation in which I basically overrid the methods `fireSelectionChanged(int offset, int length)` and `firePostSelectionChanged(int offset, int lenght)`, such that they use events containing my `ISelection`.

The rest is implementing the handling of my Objects in the Adapter for `IPropertySourceProvider` in a way that it returns an `IPropertySource` for the given Object, as it is shown in various tutorials.